# Serialization of custom data types VB.net

Tags: vb.net, serialization

I have an object that I need to serialize from VB.net to a JSON string so that I can pass it down through my REST API to an Android device. However, the object I am serializing contains custom datatypes such as:

```
Public dbPtr As New DataBasePurchaseOrderPointer(listOfFields)
```

When I pass this object through

```
Dim serializer As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim serializedObject = serializer.Serialize(obj)
```

All of the fields are empty, such as

```
{"dbPtr":""}
```

All of the object's fields contain "primitive" data types at core. For example, dbPtr is clearly a long when you read the data in the field.

Is there a way that I can pass this object through a custom serializer that can simply copy the raw values of the object's fields and then serialize them?

Comment: Are the members public? If they're private the serialize can't read them afaik

Comment: That specific one is public in the example

Comment: When the class (obj's class) is constructed any fields which are initialized are done so before the constructor code runs. I guess `listOfFields` is null when `Public dbPtr As New DataBasePurchaseOrderPointer(listOfFields)` happens. Is this possible? Step through your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve my problem, I ended up employing a "custom" serialization class that would take the current data of the object fields and put them into a dictionary. When `.ToString` is called, it converts the field data into a string that can be stuffed into a dictionary. After that, the REST API serializes the dictionary and passes it to my android application as a JSON object.

```
    Public Function serializeObject(obj As Object) As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim properties As New ArrayList

    For Each prop As FieldInfo In obj.GetType.GetFields
        properties.Add(prop)
    Next

    For Each prop In properties
        Try
            dict.Add(prop.Name, prop.getValue(obj).ToString)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace)
        End Try
    Next

    Return dict

End Function
```